# how to prevent duplicate files from being added to sate React <input type="file" >?

Tags: javascript

how to prevent duplicate files from being added to the state?

Is there an option to compare them somehow, and then write them to the state?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.